# GeneXus Extension: How to get the creation date of an object?

Tags: c#, genexus

I would like to make a GeneXus extension that analyzes recently created objects.
For example, analyze objects created  the last week, but do not take into account those objects that existed before, even if they have been modified recently.

Is there any way to get the creation date of an object with the GeneXus Platform SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `KBObject` you can retrieve any revision. In particular you may get just the first one and get it's timestamp:

```
KBObject kbObj = ...;
DateTime ts = kbObj.GetVersions().First().Timestamp;
```